# Signal conditioning for a current transducer

Tags: power-electronics, current-measurement, transducer, vector-control

I am using a current transducer (LPSR 15-NP) to measure the current that is flowing through my AC servo motor powered by my SVPWM PCB. I have currently implemented an open loop control to the motor and it is working perfectly. I need to now design a current control closed loop. For that, I am measuring the current going through the U-V-W phases of my PMSM motor. On the output I am getting a variation of 2.407V to 3.047V. I need a constant voltage so that I can implement my current loop.

How do I do this?  Are the connections for my LPSR correct or do I need to add some capacitors for signal conditioning? I do not understand why the LPSR is not simply giving me an output voltage in the range 0-5V as the datasheet suggests.

[image: Current transducer wiring in the SVPWM board]

Do I need to add a True RMS to DC converter on the output of my LPSR 15-NP to get the DC voltage I require? Do I need to add some rectification or some capacitive filtering in my output? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: This sensor output directly follows the high frequency AC current created by the SVPWM driver. Yes, you need filtering and a rectifier.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I plotted a graph on the ADC values I was receiving on the Iu voltage output and I can see that the AC sine wave is increasing in amplitude.

So can I do this filtering in my code instead of the board? It will cause a big time lag for me to design a new pcb for this purpose.

Comment: You need a high sampling rate if you want to filter this in software, but, yes, I did so myself. Have a look at the minimum load requirement in the datasheet, I am not sure what impact this might have.

Comment: I have a 19 bit ADC and the I am running my TM4C1249 controller at 120Mhz. Seems high enough sampling rate.
So I tried it. I am getting a better response with the RMS value calculation but I still see some ripples in graph. By adding a simple high pass filter to my circuit, can these ripples be removed? Or will it cause any other problems?

Comment: I would solder an R/C low pass and connect this to a scope. Then compare this with the calculated values. Is there always enough CPU power to do the math or is this lagging under some conditions, e.g. other CPU tasks?

Comment: There is a DC offset in the circuit due to the steady state condition of the current transducer. It gives a 2.5Vdc for Input current of 0A. For that I have to take the mean value of a number of readings and from that I have to determine the RMS value. This is causing a a bit of lag

Comment: Also one more thing. When I take the RMS value I always get a positive current value. For the SVPWM current feedback control to work I also need to know the direction of current for all three phases U,V,W of the motor, since the sum of the three current Ia, Ib and Ic needs to be equal to 0. Now how do i see the direction of the current?

Comment: But the sensor delivers a signed value relative to the center voltage of 2.5 V. This includes the current direction.

Comment: No, actually the average value remains at 2.5V. Only the peak to peak voltage increases as the current going through the transducer increases. Now, whether the current is going in one direction or the other, I am not able it figure it out from the transducer.

Comment: No, the LPSR series are true bipolar devices. The signal is a signed value Vout - Vref, where Vref is 2.5 V. The switching transients of PWM current reversal may have such a high amplitute, that you don't see the effective current in this noise. There may be capacitive coupling from the phase line into your ADC. Apply a low frequency sine wave current to verify the bipolar nature of the output.

Comment: What you are saying technically makes sense, and after reading the datasheet it should work like that. But it doesnt. I connected the AC supply that is 50 Hz with this current transducer across a load and the response is same as before. Constant at 2.5V DC offset and a AC peak to peak increase only as the current increases.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I basically did was I made a comparator circuit to remove the 2.5V DC offset from the response. Then I received the values in my ADC. I calculated the RMS values for Ia and Ib. Ic can be calculated by this formula:

Ia + Ib + Ic = 0

Then I did the clark transform to get Ialpha and Ibeta.

Then I applied the park transform to get the Id and Iq values. I calculated the RMS value of Id and Iq once again. This seems to give me a steady state response. Id needs to be close to zero and Iq needs to increase as the current across the motor increase. I am not sure why this works but this is what I did. If there is a problem in my methodology please let me know.

I am going to try and implement the current PI control on Id_ref = 0 and Iq_ref = User defined, and then see how it goes.